# Getting Word Events while using SpeechLib

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-to-speech

```
using SpeechLib;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SpeakToFile(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    static void SpeakToFile(string toSpeak)
    {
        SpVoice v = new SpVoice();
        v.EventInterests = SpeechVoiceEvents.SVEAllEvents;
        v.Word += V_Word;

        SpFileStream speechStream = new SpFileStream();

        speechStream.Open("D:/Documenten/test.mp3", SpeechStreamFileMode.SSFMCreateForWrite, true);

        v.AudioOutputStream = speechStream;
        v.Rate = 0;
        v.Speak(toSpeak, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
        speechStream.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void V_Word(int StreamNumber, object StreamPosition, int CharacterPosition, int Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CharacterPosition);`
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the Word Events to show up in the Console. But this is not working.

I've searched for answers on the Internet but I can't find anything about this.

Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `But this is not working.` Tell us more about what you mean by `not working`.

Comment: `D:/Documenten/test.mp3` Does it work if you use \\ instead of / ?

Comment: The text-to-speech part is working. It creates an mp3-file with the speech in it. Ultimately i want to create a text-file with the Word Events in it. But it seems like it doesn't call the V_Word function, because nothing is showing up in the Console.